# How am I supposed to understand the penalty term to penalize lack of smoothness?

Tags: regularization, intuition, smoothing

The penalty term is written as $\lambda\int f''(t)^2 dt$.

I am told that if $f$ is wiggly, then $f''$ is big, so this term penalizes the lack of smoothness of $f$.

Uh, okay, that makes sense ... but then you take the integral? Why?

How do you know that integral converges? That doesn't make sense. In fact, for many smooth functions, $\int f''(t)^2 dt = \infty$. For example, take $f(x) = x^2$. Then $f''(x) = 2$, and the integral is infinity, so what's the point?

My question is basically what that integral is doing there. Now you can only work with functions for which that integral is finite, which you have no way of knowing??

Comment: Welcome to CV! The example you give ($f(x)=x^2)$ is a perfectly smooth function, while the point of the penalty is to regularize functions that otherwise aren't smooth. Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410554/176202

Comment: As to why the integral in the first place: A model with finite parameterization takes a penalty for the sum of (some function of) its coefficients. The continuous version of a sum is an integral.

Comment: The penalty term is often imposed in situations where we are using basis functions, so that $f(x) = \sum b_i(x) \alpha_i$ where $b_i$ is a basis function and $\alpha_i$ is a constant. So how would it then work if we take the basis functions to be polynomials, so that $b_1 = 1, b_2 = x, b_3 = x^2, b_4 = x^3, ...$. In that case, how does the penalty term make sense? Is the integral still not infinity ?

Comment: You don't really consider the integral to be over $(-\infty, \infty)$, but rather over the range of the values of the data, which is where the estimation occurs.  If I am estimating a function with variable $x \in (0,4)$, I don't really care what the penalty term does to, e.g., a function value for $x = 1\times 10^6$.

Comment: What you have is *a* penalty term. It only gets the definite article "the" in a context where it, specifically the penalty term for that context but you supply no context. Your question would be clearer if you did. For example are you talking about cubic spline smoothing?

Comment: This integral always converges: it just might be infinite.  However, it is obvious that in such a case $f$ would not be a solution, because we can always find solutions where the integral does converge.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

- We need to penalize the *function*, not some of its values, so somehow you need to summarize all the individual values. Taking the integral (continuous sum) seems natural.
- We do not think about the integral range as $(-\infty, +\infty)$, but rather as the data range. So divergence of the integral shouldn't be a concern. Even then, if we should have an infinite integral, then the penalty will be $\infty$, so that is regularized away!
- Generally, we work with some known basis functions, and know (or can approximate) their second derivatives. So your concerns could be investigated in any concrete case.

See also the comments below the question.

Comment: The reason for (2) is simple: you can always extend $f$ outside the data range linearly.  That implies $f^{\prime\prime}$ is identically zero outside the data range, guaranteeing convergence of the entire integral.  If the space spanned by the basis functions does not include such functions, then we're in trouble: we have to relax our requirements on $f$ near the endpoints of the data range.